# How can i change logo of OsTicket for email?

Tags: php, osticket

I must remove logo and label of OsTicket in footer for each email templates.

I've deleted footer in each template in:
`D:\support\osticket\include\i18n\en_US\templates\email\`

However users still receive letters with logo and label of osTicket.

For ex.

`D:\support\osticket\include\i18n\en_US\templates\email\ticket.alert.yaml`

```
#
# Email template: ticket.alert.yaml
#
# Sent to a staff member when a new ticket is created in the system. This
# applies to tickets created via email, the web portal, or the api.
#
---
notes: |
    Sent to a staff member when a new ticket is created in the system. This
    applies to tickets created via email, the web portal, or the api.

subject: |
    New Ticket Alert
body: |
    <h2>Hi %{recipient.name},</h2>
    New ticket #%{ticket.number} created
    <br>
    <br>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>From</strong>:
        </td>
        <td>
            %{ticket.name} &lt;%{ticket.email}&gt;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>Department</strong>:
        </td>
        <td>
            %{ticket.dept.name}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    %{message}
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the footer you need to go to 
Admin -> Emails -> Templates -> Choose the template that is in use and from there go through all of the templates and delete the osticket value.

You don't need to change it from backend.

[image]